# How to overlap spinner options over a button like Youtube or Linkedin

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm looking for a way to have an invisible spinner that can be triggered when the "More" button is pressed.

I currently have a spinner that appears next to the button. At the moment only the drop down arrow is visible. Using "spinner.performclick()' the spinner opens when the button is clicked. I would like the

the spinner does open but the spinner options do not aligend to the button.

I've tried to set the visibility of the spinner to GONE but this also hides the spinner options.

Example from Youtube

[image: Example from Youtube]

Comment: show not a spinner, but a popupMenu or popupWindow. You can control it's position

Comment: Good. I won't make a full answer, as my comment has to be extended alot to become a good answer, and you already got it working, so probably somebody else wants to make a full answer and gain reputation.